# Javafx buttons not functioning properly, and pane not resizing

Tags: java, javafx, alignment, javafx-2, pane

Currently the code below produces a BorderPane with a GridPane in the center and a HBox on the bottom to hold two buttons.  The left-most pane in the GridPane contains the text "Name Here". Right now I only want the buttons to move the text "Name Here" up and down but they will not move the text.

I think it has something to do with the particular GridPane node, but I'm not sure.  Additionally, I don't know why the left-most GridPane takes up more space relative to the right-most GridPane within the center of the BorderPane.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.geometry.HPos;
    import javafx.geometry.VPos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;   


    public class differentWindows extends Application {

      protected Text name = new Text("Name Here");

      protected BorderPane getPane() {

      // HBox to hold the up and down buttons
      HBox paneForButtons = new HBox(20);
      Button btUp = new Button("Up");
      Button btDown = new Button("Down");
      paneForButtons.getChildren().addAll(btUp, btDown);
      paneForButtons.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

      // Grid pane to go in center of the border pane, for the name and video    
      GridPane paneForTextNVideo = new GridPane();
      paneForTextNVideo.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      paneForTextNVideo.setGridLinesVisible(true);
      paneForTextNVideo.add(name, 0, 0);

      Text temp = new Text("temp");
      paneForTextNVideo.add(temp, 1, 0);
      paneForTextNVideo.setHalignment(temp, HPos.CENTER);
      paneForTextNVideo.setValignment(temp, VPos.CENTER);
      paneForTextNVideo.setHgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);
      paneForTextNVideo.setVgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);

      paneForTextNVideo.setHalignment(name, HPos.CENTER);
      paneForTextNVideo.setValignment(name, VPos.CENTER);
      paneForTextNVideo.setHgrow(name, Priority.ALWAYS);
      paneForTextNVideo.setVgrow(name, Priority.ALWAYS);

      // Border pane to hold all windows
      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      pane.setBottom(paneForButtons);  
      pane.setCenter(paneForTextNVideo);

      btUp.setOnAction(e -> name.setY(name.getY() - 10));
      btDown.setOnAction(e -> name.setY(name.getY() + 10));

      return pane;     

      } // end of the getPane method


      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      Scene scene = new Scene(getPane(), 450, 200);
      primaryStage.setTitle("Assignment #7");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();

      } // end of start method

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Application.launch(args);
      }

    } // end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setLayoutY` instead of `setY`:

```
btUp.setOnAction(e -> name.setLayoutY(name.getLayoutY() - 10));
btDown.setOnAction(e -> name.setLayoutY(name.getLayoutY() + 10));
```

---

As a sidenote, the `Node` parent class also has a [relocate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#relocate-double-double-) method for easily changing both the X and Y coordinates:

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it as accepted both for anyone who comes across it in the future and for myself.